Unexpected behavior and TypeError: missing 1 required positional or keyword argument from implementing stripe.CustomerService.create()
I am using the stripe library. I keep receiving a TypeError: StripeService._request() missing 1 required positional or keyword argument exception. I am invoking the function within a class the extends or inherits functionality from the StripeObject. When I invoke stripe.CustomerService.create(self=stripe.CustomerService, options=customer_options) with or without the arguments or when I explicitly declare or assign parameters I get the  exceptions. It is usually the 'url' argument in _request() that is missing; I peeked into the code and the url argument is a positional parameter that comes after another positional parameter both which are in the function call and signature but not explicitly assigned as default parameter values. My research suggests this can occur if I didn't properly create an instance of the class, but that is not the case unless it is because I am implementing the stripe.CustomerService.create() within another function within a class? So a possible solution: would be to create an instance of the CustomerService class within the function, but that requires a 'request' object to be passed and I looked at the code and I think it is needs a httpclient and request options (an object of key/values i.e. api_key).
class MLH_Stripe(StripeObject):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    
    def RequestCall(self, url: Optional[str] = None) -> json:
        # r = requests.Request('GET', URL)
        header = {
           'Authorization' : API_KEY 
        }
        response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=header)
        # print(r)
        # print(response.json())
        return response.json()


    # create customer data to [initial test data]
    app.post('/v1/customers')
    def CreateCustomer(self) -> stripe.Customer:
        customer_options =  {
                #  'id'  :  "cus_NffrFeUfNV2Hib",
                'Address'  :  None,
                'Balance'  :  0,
                'CashBalance' : None,
                # 'created'  :  1680893993,
                #  'currency'  :  None,
                #  'default_source'  :  None,
                #  'delinquent'  :  False,
                'Description'  :  None,
                # 'discount'  :  None,
                 'Email'  :  "jennyrosen@example.com",
                #  'invoice_prefix'  :  "0759376C",
                'InvoiceSettings'  :  {
                     'CustomFields'  :  None,
                     'DefaultPaymentMethod'  :  None,
                     'Footer'  :  None,
                     'RenderingOptions'  :  None
                },
                #  'livemode'  :  False,
                'PaymentMethod' : "card",
                'Metadata'  :  {},
                'Name'  :  "Jenny Rosen",
                #  'next_invoice_sequence'  :  1,
                'Phone'  :  None,
                'Plan' : None,
                'PreferredLocales'  :  ["en-US"],
                'Shipping'  :  None,
                'TaxExempt'  :  None,
                'TestClock'  :  None
                }
       
        return  stripe.CustomerService.create(self=stripe.CustomerService, options=customer_options)

Why is this occurring? It doesn't make sense based on the information I have.

You are calling stripe.CustomerService.create but I cannot find a definition of that in the stripe documentation. Do you have a link to a different source?

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm also very confused by what this code refers to. The Stripe Python library doesn't include anything structured like this https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create?lang=python This looks more like something you'd find for the .NET framework https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create?lang=dotnet

I couldn't find the definition in the stripe documentation either, but I can assure you that it is there. I found it by exploring the library and interpreting the code. You have two classes: Customer and CustomerService. The former is recommended by the docs and makes a static request but doesn't have as many options or arguments as the latter. I think the key difference is that it is a class method and the static part. @OldBoy

@Lucky2501 yeah, you're definitely right, but I have seen the design pattern before. In fact stripe does it with cast from the typing module to convert the return value to the object that called it to ensure type compatibility.

"I found it by exploring the library and interpreting the code". OK, but you are still missing something, as clearly stated in the error message.
